# How to create 1 row below 2 colums with CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css

Using CSS Grid I'm trying to create a blurb layout that has 2 columns at the top with 1 full row below.

This would allow for FA Icon and Title, with full description underneath, like the image below.

I think I've got the grid layout, but I'm unsure how to make the width of the top 2 columns (`icon` and `title`) shift together and auto-fit to the contents?

Would this be easier with firebox?

Thanks,

[image]

[CodePen Link](https://codepen.io/Rosko34/pen/LYeZpKJ)

HMTL

```
<div class="main_description_container">
<div class="description_gridwrapper">
    <div id="icon"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"><!--tr--></i></div>
    <div id="title"><h3>Title Text</h3></div>
    <div id="text">Long Paragraph Text</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.main_description_container{
display: block;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
}

.description_gridwrapper {
display: grid; 
grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
gap: 0px;
height: 100%;
}
  
.description_gridwrapper #icon {
   background-color: #68dd99; 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 2;
}

.description_gridwrapper #icon i.fas{
color: #B1DDF1;
font-size: 36px !important;
max-width: 36px !important;
width: 36px !important;
}

.description_gridwrapper #title {
   background-color: #D75DDC; 
   grid-row-start: 1;
   grid-column-start: 2;
   grid-row-end: 2;
   grid-column-end: 3;
color: #31324E;
}

.description_gridwrapper #text {
   background-color: #9FDABB; 
   grid-row-start: 2;
   grid-column-start: 1;
   grid-row-end: 3;
   grid-column-end: 3;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just let the text-block span both columns with `grid-column: span 2`. See comments within CSS

```css
/* creates a 2 column grid where the first column for the icon only uses as much space as required and the 2nd column the remaining space */
.description_gridwrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: min-content auto;
}

/* removes the default margin of the title to be in same line as the icon */
#title h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

/* lets the tex-block use both columns */
#text {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_description_container">
<div class="description_gridwrapper">
    <div id="icon"><i class="fas fa-info-circle">ICON</i></div>
    <div id="title"><h3>Title Text</h3></div>
    <div id="text">Long Paragraph Text</div>
</div>
</div>
```